# Could not delete DC/OS service that was failed to deploy

Tags: mesos, mesosphere, dcos

I deployed a service in DC/OS (the service is cassandra).  The deployment failed and it kept retrying.  Under DC/OS > Services > Tasks I could see a new task was created every a few minutes, but they all had the status of "Failed".  Under the Debug tab I could see the TASK_FAILED state with a error message about how I misconfigured the service (I picked a user that does not exist).

So I wanted to destroy the service and start over again.

Under Services, I clicked on the menu on the service and selected "Delete".  The command was taken, and the Status changed to "Deleting"  But then it stayed there forever.

If I checked the Tasks tab, I could see that DC/OS was still attempting to start the server every a few minutes.

Now how do I delete the service?  Thanks!

Comment: what version of DC/OS are you using?

Comment: @M I P - I believe the version is 1.11  Thanks!  By the way, I restarted the cluster.  After that, all the services were gone (both the successfully deployed one and those who failed to deploy).  I am very new to this and don't know yet how to keep the services that I want to restart upon cluster restart

Answer (score 0):

As per latest DCOS cassandra servicce [docs](https://docs.mesosphere.com/services/cassandra/2.2.0-3.0.16/uninstall/), you should uninstall it using dcos cli :

```
dcos package uninstall --app-id=<service-name> cassandra
```

If you are using DCOS 1.9 or older version, then follow below steps to uninstall service :

```
$ MY_SERVICE_NAME=<service-name>
$ dcos package uninstall --app-id=$MY_SERVICE_NAME cassandra`.
$ dcos node ssh --master-proxy --leader "docker run mesosphere/janitor /janitor.py \
-r $MY_SERVICE_NAME-role \
-p $MY_SERVICE_NAME-principal \
-z dcos-service-$MY_SERVICE_NAME"
```